# AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'df_new' in python when replacing string

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

I am writing a short piece of code to remove web browser version numbers from the name in a column of data in a pandas dataframe. i.e. replace a string containing alpha and numerical characters with just the alpha characters.

I have written:

```
df_new=(rename())

str.replace.df_new[new_browser]('[.*0-9]',"",regex=True)
```

I am getting this error message and I don't understand what it's telling me

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d8c6f9119b9f> in <module>
      3 df_new=(rename())
      4 
----> 5 str.replace.df_new[new_browser]('[.*0-9]',"",regex=True)

AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'df_new'
```

The code above is following this code/function in a Jupyter Notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

    #write a function to change column names using a dictionary
    
    def rename():
        dict_col = {'Browser':'new_browser', 'Page':'web_page', 'URL':'web_address', 'Visitor ID':'visitor_ID'}
        df = pd.read_csv ('dummy_webchat_data.csv')
        for y in df.columns:
            if y in dict_col:
                df_new=df.rename(columns={y:dict_col}[y])
            
        return df_new

rename()
```

I've been having trouble with the dataframe updates not being recognised when I next call it. Usually in JN I just keep writing the amends to the df and it retains the updates. But even the code `df_new.head(1)` needs to be written like this to work after the first function is run for some reason (mentioning as it feels like a similar problem even though the error messages are different):

```
df_new=(rename())
df_new.head(1)
```

can anyone help me please?

Best

Miriam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you are not using the `Series.str.replace()` method correctly.

You have:

`str.replace.df_new[new_browser]('[.*0-9]',"",regex=True)`

when what you want is:

`df_new[new_browser].str.replace('[.*0-9]',"",regex=True)`

See this:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> s = pd.Series(['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'])
>>> s.str.replace('[.*0-9]',"",regex=True)
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
dtype: object
```

and compare it with this (which is what you get, `s` here is your `df_new[new_browser]`):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> s = pd.Series(['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'])
>>> str.replace.s('[.*0-9]',"",regex=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 's'
```

Comment: thank you, that's really helpful. I had it the other way around having read some other Q&A on here but that was replace all admittedly and not str.replace